# How to test the output of code in ACE editor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-editor

Like Codecademy, and it saves the data for different users. Ive been looking for ages, but havent come up with anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a Rails live-editor available, since Rails requires a database instance and a server-side process, making such an endeavor expensive (and not particularly useful). But you can get what you're looking for -- a persistent, easy Rails setup -- with a [free Heroku dyno](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) and a [quickstart guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4).

Comment: Ok thanks :) but do you know how Codecademy does theirs?

Comment: I don't believe they make the exact details of how their setup works public, but [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/How-do-sites-like-CodeCombat-CodeCademy-and-CodeWars-safely-execute-and-test-code-entered-by-the-users-What-would-their-architecture-look-like#!n=12) has some speculation. I think you'd learn more from playing around on an actual server, though.